# how to create countdown onClickListener in android

Tags: android, listener

The scenario is like if the user touches a view and holds the view for a specified seconds.
something like a long focus listener but with a specified timer if the user takes the finger off before the timer then it won't invoke action. Is it possible? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// This example shows an Activity, but you would use the same approach if
// you were subclassing a View.
//Declare timer
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;    
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

    switch(action) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) :
            startTimer();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was DOWN");
            return true;
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) :
            cancelTimer();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Action was UP");
            return true;
        default :
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //you can keep updating the ui here.
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            //this is where you want to do something on the basis on long tap action.
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}
void cancelTimer() {
    if(cTimer!=null)
        cTimer.cancel();
}
}
```

you can look ahead for MotionEvents at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector).